# XML serialization of a class in another class

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

these are the classes I'm working with currently.

```
public class Monster
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name;
    public int Mana;
    public int Health;
    public List<Drop> Drops;    
}
public class Drop
{
    public string DropInfo;
}
```

This is the XML:

```
<Monster name="TestMonster1">
  <Health>5</Health>
  <Mana>2</Mana>
  <Drops>
    <Drop>124 20 40</Drop>
    <Drop>140 15 25</Drop>
    <Drop>155 10 15</Drop>
  </Drops>
</Monster>
```

What I want to do is add each `<Drop>` of the XML into the Drop List. I've tried different combinations of XmlArray, XmlArrayItem and XmlElement but none of them have worked.

Right now the Drop class only has a string, but it will have more as I need to process that string, that's why the `List<Drop>` isn't just an array of strings.

Is it possible to do? The only thing I managed to do was to get the List to have 3 items which is correct, but the string always was null.

Comment: Have you tried to put [XmlText] over DropInfo?

Comment: Wow, I actually havn't tried this yet, but yes, it works! Havn't done a lot with this XML stuff so it's still pretty new to me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I added it as an answer so people can easily find the solution in the future :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're lacking [XmlText] in DropInfo. C# doesn't know where to stick the text within the `<Drop>` tags without it:

```
public class Drop
{
    [XmlText]
    public string DropInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ths

```
    public class Monster
    {
        [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public string Name;
        public int Mana;
        public int Health;
        [XmlArray("Drops")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Drop")]
        public List<Drop> Drops;
    }

    public class Drop
    {
        [XmlText]
        public string DropInfo;
    }
}
```

see it working in my .NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HzvVkI

Comment: Hey, even though you're correct too, Johns answer was earlier that's why I accepted his! But thanks anyway.